# Doorkeeper::AccessToken + Mongoid: Query all expired tokens

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, access-token, doorkeeper

I have a lot of `access_tokens` stored with Mongoid4. I want to query all expired and non expired tokens, based on their `expires_in` field, which is in seconds, and the `created_at` field, which has the type Time.

The two fields looks like this:

```
field :created_at, type: Time
field :expires_in, type: Integer
```

I know I can query by date like this `Doorkeeper::AccessToken.where(created_at: (3.days.ago..Time.now))`.

But how do I compare the `created_at` field and the `expires_in` field in one query? I want to have all access tokens, where the `created_at` field plus the seconds from the `expires_in` are smaller or greater compared to `Time.now`. Is this even possible? Or do I have to iterate over all entries, and select them by hand?

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to do something with Mongoid's MapReduce feature here, but a simple way might be to first select the max expires_in value and then query for:

```
Doorkeeper::AccessToken.where(created_at: (3.days.ago..Time.now-max_expires_in))
```

which gives you a list of tokens you know are outside the range.

Then you could do:

```
Doorkeeper::AccessToken.where(created_at: ((Time.now-max_expires_in)..Time.now))
```

for a smaller list you'd have to filter manually.